# Get complete data in this code

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is parent child relationship code and i get Only id but I want to get complete data in this array

```
public function create_duplicate_pages()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('select_page');

    $test = $this->categoryChild($id);

    print_r($test);
    die;

}

public function categoryChild($id) 
{
    $s = "SELECT * FROM static_pages WHERE parent_bit = $id";

    $r = mysql_query($s);

    $children = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) 
        {
            $children[$row['id']] = $this->categoryChild($row['id']);
        }
    }

    if(empty($children))
    {
        return "No Child";
    }
    else
    {
        return $children;
    }

}
```

This is parent child relationship code and i get Only id but I want to get complete data in this array

Comment: Don't use mysql_query, it has been deprecated. Use mysqli.

Comment: Add `categoryChild()` to your question

Answer (score 0):

**Change:**

```
$children[$row['id']] = $this->categoryChild($row['id']);
```

**to:**

```
$children[$row['id']][] = $row;
```

Comment: not use this code because this is simple get data not use for recursive function but i want to get complete data in recursive function

Comment: @BilalSheikh repalce it $children[$row['id']][] = $this->categoryChild($row['id']);

Comment: i use your code but not get complete data 
This code only make multilevel array I want to get complete data in parent and child data

Comment: @BilalSheikh print rows how many rows it returns `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) { var_dump($row); }`

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) { var_dump($row); }
but throw error like
A PHP Error was encountered
Message: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @BilalSheikh first print query result, Is executed successfully?

Comment: @BilalSheikh change query "SELECT * FROM static_pages WHERE parent_bit = '".$id.'"";

Comment: @BilalSheikh print mysql_num_rows()

Comment: I print the row then get 32 rows return in use this code
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) { var_dump($row); }

Comment: @BilalSheikh then print `$row = mysql_fetch_array($r); print($row);`

Comment: I get only parent data in use this code like
$row = mysql_fetch_array($r); print($row);
Just print parent data but i want to complete data parent and child and multilevel child

Comment: @BilalSheikh 'while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
   echo $row['id'];
}'

Comment: @ Suneel Kumar Just get parent id not get child id

Comment: not get complete data for use this code
 while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) { echo $row['id']; } only get parent id

Comment: @BilalSheikh are you using Codeigniter framework right?

Comment: @BilalSheikh `if ($r->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($r->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->id;    
   }
}`  replace this

Comment: @ Suneel Kumar error on this code
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in

Comment: @BilalSheikh use instead $r->num_rows instead of $r->num_rows()

Comment: can you send me email i send to database single table and send function to parent child relationship code and i get Only complete ids but I want to get complete data in this array

Comment: suneel2you@gmail.com

Comment: check email and test code with database table i am waiting for your reply thanks

Comment: Yes just now, I will send mail to u.

Answer (score 0):

1. Currently `$children[$row['id']]` is string. Add `[]` right after `$children[$row['id']]` to make it `array`.
2. You are storing value INDEX `ID` only to variable. To store all values use `$this->categoryChild($row)` instead of `$this->categoryChild($row['id'])`

By the way, what `categoryChild()` does?

**Note**:

> `mysql_query` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: categoryChild()
This is a recursive function to get child

Comment: @BilalSheikh if my answer does not works for you, then share the code of this function

Comment: i use this code for recursive function
public function categoryChild($id) 
{
    $s = "SELECT * FROM static_pages WHERE parent_bit = $id";

    $r = mysql_query($s);

    $children = array();

    if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) 
        {
            $children[$row['id']] = $this->categoryChild($row['id']);
        }
    }

    if(empty($children))
    {
        return "No Child";
    }
    else
    {
        return $children;
    }